# Where in the registry does CoCreateInstance() look? Delphi

Tags: delphi, registry

Where in the registry does `CoCreateInstance()` look?

Looking for the Class ID: `{000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` (Microsoft Word Application)

My guess is `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\LocalServer32` if I'm looking for that Class ID. Can I get a confirmation?

Delphi calls:

```pascal
CoWordApplication.Create;
```

That calls:

```pascal
CreateComObject(CLASS_WordApplication) as _Application;
```

and that calls:

```pascal
OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(ClassID, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or
        CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IUnknown, Result));
```

Comment: Yes, it looks in `HKCR\CLSID\{guid}\InprocServer32` and/or `HKCR\CLSID\{guid}\LocalServer32`, depending on the specified flags

Comment: I appreciate the fast confirmation Remy.